# ¿Cómo dividir un diccionario en python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

como puedo dividir un diccionario de esta forma: 
diccionario_Original={1: [1, 2, 3, 4], 2: [1, 2, 3, 4]}

Diccionario_Dividido({1: [1], 2: [1, 2, 3, 4]}, {1: [2, 3, 4], 2: [1, 2, 3, 4]})

exactamente necesito tomar el valor del primer elemento del diccionario y dividirlo en dos partes, formando 2 diccionarios como en el ejemplo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ya que entiendo que el diccionario original no debe resultar afectado, hago un par de copias de él y después en cada una de las copias actualizo el elemento con *key*=1:

```
>>> diccionario_Original={1: [1, 2, 3, 4], 2: [1, 2, 3, 4]}
>>> primero = diccionario_Original.copy()
>>> segundo = diccionario_Original.copy()
>>> primero[1] = primero[1][0:1]
>>> segundo[1] = segundo[1][1:]
>>> primero, segundo
({1: [1], 2: [1, 2, 3, 4]}, {1: [2, 3, 4], 2: [1, 2, 3, 4]})
```

Ten en cuenta no obstante que el concepto "el primer elemento del diccionario" es erróneo. Los diccionarios no tienen un orden interno. Si por primer elemento te refieres al elemento con clave 1, entonces sí sería correcto.